# MERGE INTO USING from dual (ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, merge

My query below was working, I swear... now suddenly, it's ***dead***, outputting '`ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected`'.. I cannot understand why... I have tried various linters and syntax checkers; I am simply iterating through array data and pushing to a oracle table/row - adding a new entry if `table_id` is not found, and updating `table_id` if it is found. What am I missing?

Data coming in is perfect too.. what am I doing incorrectly..

```
    $fd = json_decode($df, true);

    foreach ($fd as $key=>$data) {

        var_dump($data);
 
        $sql = "MERGE INTO app.table a 
        using (SELECT '${data[0]}'    table_id, 
                      '${data[1]}'    fac_ident, 
                      '${data[2]}'    lg_name, 
                      '${data[3]}'    basic_tp, 
                      '${data[4]}'    catc_vd, 
                      '${data[5]}'    address, 
                      '${data[6]}'    assoc_city, 
                      '${data[7]}'    latitude, 
                      '${data[8]}'    longitude, 
                      '${data[9]}'    assoc_cnty, 
                      '${data[10]}'   assoc_st, 
                      '${data[11]}'   time_zone, 
               FROM   dual) p 
        ON ( a.table_id = p.table_id ) 
        WHEN matched THEN 
          UPDATE SET a.fac_ident = p.fac_ident, 
                     a.lg_name = p.lg_name, 
                     a.basic_tp = p.basic_tp, 
                     a.catc_vd = p.catc_vd, 
                     a.address = p.address, 
                     a.assoc_city = p.assoc_city, 
                     a.latitude = p.latitude, 
                     a.longitude = p.longitude, 
                     a.assoc_cnty = p.assoc_cnty, 
                     a.assoc_st = p.assoc_st, 
                     a.time_zone = p.time_zone, 
        WHEN NOT matched THEN 
          INSERT (table_id, 
                  fac_ident, 
                  lg_name, 
                  basic_tp, 
                  catc_vd, 
                  address, 
                  assoc_city, 
                  latitude, 
                  longitude, 
                  assoc_cnty, 
                  assoc_st, 
                  time_zone) 
          VALUES (p.table_id, 
                  p.fac_ident, 
                  p.lg_name, 
                  p.basic_tp, 
                  p.catc_vd, 
                  p.address, 
                  p.assoc_city, 
                  p.latitude, 
                  p.longitude, 
                  p.assoc_cnty, 
                  p.assoc_st, 
                  p.time_zone)";
                  ..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data contains a single quote then you are doing the equivalent of trying to perform an SQL injection attack.

Don't use variable parsing `${data[0]}`; instead create your query using bind variables and pass in your data properly so you are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

For example:

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  table_id  VARCHAR2(100),
  fac_ident VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

And you have a `table_id` of `1` and a `fac_ident` of `2` then your merge would be:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name a
USING (
  SELECT '1' table_id,
         '2' fac_ident
  FROM   dual
) p 
ON ( a.table_id = p.table_id ) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.fac_ident = p.fac_ident
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
  INSERT (table_id, fac_ident ) 
  VALUES (p.table_id, p.fac_ident );
```

This works.

However, if `fac_ident` has the value `This value has a 'quote' inside it.` then your query is:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name a
USING (
  SELECT '1' table_id,
         'This value has a 'quote' inside it.' fac_ident
  FROM   dual
) p 
ON ( a.table_id = p.table_id ) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.fac_ident = p.fac_ident
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
  INSERT (table_id, fac_ident ) 
  VALUES (p.table_id, p.fac_ident );
```

And fails with:

> ```
> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> ```

More insidious, is if `fac_indent` has the value `'||(SELECT secret_column FROM secret_data WHERE ROWNUM = 1)||'` and then your query becomes:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name a
USING (
  SELECT '1' table_id,
         ''||(SELECT secret_column FROM secret_data WHERE ROWNUM = 1)||'' fac_ident
  FROM   dual
) p 
ON ( a.table_id = p.table_id ) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.fac_ident = p.fac_ident
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
  INSERT (table_id, fac_ident ) 
  VALUES (p.table_id, p.fac_ident );
```

And, if the table `SECRET_DATA` exists and has the column `SECRET_COLUMN` then your query won't fail and users can start to do unexpected things with your query. Please don't let them do this and use best practice of formulating your queries using bind variables rather than string concatenation.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c566c9fc2d24003ac97a44d66ca1c22)*